What should I do if data is not saved in Django?
I'm new to Django. And I'm faced with the problem of saving data from the form to the database. I was writing code in PyCharm. The main problem is that the data is not saved in the database. There are no errors, no warnings, NOTHING. Everything works except saving. I will be very grateful for your help!
Here is the code:
views.py:
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Articles
from .forms import ArticlesForm


def news_home(request):
    news = Articles.objects.order_by('title')
    return render(request, 'news/news_home.html', {'news': news})


def create(request):
    error = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ArticlesForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            article = form.save()
            return redirect('news_home')
        else:
            error = 'Unfortunately, the form was not filled out correctly.'

    form = ArticlesForm()

    data = {
        'form': form,
        'error': error
    }
    return render(request, 'news/create.html', data)

models.py:
from django.db import models


class Articles(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('name', max_length=50)
    anons = models.CharField('anons', max_length=250)
    full_text = models.TextField('article')
    date = models.DateTimeField('Date of publication')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'news'
        verbose_name_plural = 'news'

forms.py:
from .models import Articles
from django.forms import ModelForm, TextInput, DateTimeInput, Textarea


class ArticlesForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Articles
        fields = ['title', 'anons', 'full_text', 'date']

        widgets = {
            "title": TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'the name of the record'
            }),
            "anons": TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Announcement of the recording'
            }),
            "full_text": Textarea(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'write about something'
            }),
            "date": DateTimeInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Date of publication'
            }),
        }

create.py:
{% extends 'main/layout.html' %}

{% block title%}Create article{% endblock %}

{% block content%}
    <div class="features">
        <h1>Create article</h1>
        <form action="{% url 'create' %}" method="POST" class="post-form">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.title }}<br>
            {{ form.anons }}<br>
            {{ form.full_text }}<br>
            {{ form.date }}<br>
            <span>{{ error }}</span>
            <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Create article</button>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

news_home.py:
{% extends 'main/layout.html' %}

{% block title%}news{% endblock %}

{% block content%}
    <div class="features">
        <h1>news</h1>
        {% if news %}
            {% for el in news %}
                <div class="alert alert-warning">
                    <h3>{{ el.title }}</h3>
                    <p>{{ el.anons }}</p>
                    <p>{{ el.full_text }}</p>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
            <p>Unfortunately, there are no entries on the site at the moment</p>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}

urls.py:
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('main.urls')),
    path('news/', include('news.urls')),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT),

I've tried a lot of YouTube videos and articles from the Internet, but all in vain.
UPD: I also looked at the documentation.

Please post your template where the user submits the form.

I'm sorry, but how do I do this?

Edit your question adding your create.html code.

I did, I hope you can help me

I've tried your code and it works perfectly on my machine, including the saving.  Are you sure it is not saving?  Have you checked the admin page?  The only thing I can think of is that the issue might be in the news_home.html file.  Please add that to your question along with the urls.py.

I did, I hope you can help me

After "form = ArticlesForm(request.POST)" add print(form), to see what you recieved in the backend.
In else condition change it to make more meaningful error:
def form_invalid: print(form.errors) return super().form_invalid(form)
You do not need errors='' in general, errors are handling by default by django.

I didn't understand exactly what I needed to do.

we've all been there. The issue is with your def create() view function in your views.py file. the line article = form.save() is unnecessary in this case. However, you can use it if you wish. Here are 2 different implementations.
Simpler Method
def create(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ArticlesForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()  # Save the article
        return redirect('news_home')  # Redirect after POST
    else:
        error = 'Unfortunately, the form was not filled out correctly.'
else:
    form = ArticlesForm()  # Initialize a blank form for GET requests
    error = ''  # No error initially on GET request

context = {
    'form': form,
    'error': error
}
return render(request, 'news/create.html', context)

Your Method
def create(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ArticlesForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        article = form.save(commit==False)  # here we assign form to article
        # perform some task here like setting author to user: article.author = request.user
        article.save()
        return redirect('news_home')  # Redirect after POST
    else:
        error = 'Unfortunately, the form was not filled out correctly.'
else:
    form = ArticlesForm()  # Initialize a blank form for GET requests
    error = ''  # No error initially on GET request

context = {
    'form': form,
    'error': error
}
return render(request, 'news/create.html', context)

Both methods will work but I'll say stick to the simpler one. Happy coding.

This answer is wrong.

@raphael could you explain so we all learn?

How @user24993423 solved the problem, I do not know.  In your simpler method you have commit==False, but it should be commit=False (assignment versus comparison).  Anyway commit=False means it will not save, or commit anything to the database, so the simpler method will not work at all.  The one you title Your Method is actually not what the OP wrote in the question, and while it may work, it isn't needed in this case, since there are no tasks to do before saving the model.
